# The program gave the error: discord.errors.ClientException: Already playing audio. and i don't know why

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL
print("IMPORTED")

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot

        # all the music related stuff
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        # 2d array containing [song, channel]
        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
                               'options': '-vn'}

        self.vc = None
    def search_yt(self, item):
        try:
            ydl = YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS)
            info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'][0]
        except Exception:
            return False

        return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}

    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        while len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True
            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            # Now connect to the voice channel
            try:
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()
            except:
                print("Bot already connected")

            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            async def after_play(error):
                await self.play_music(ctx)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS),after=after_play)
            self.is_playing = False
        else:
            print("huh")
            self.is_playing = False
    @commands.command(name="play")
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)
        voice_channel = "a"
        #anti spam system

        if ctx.author.voice is None:
        # you need to be connected so that the bot knows where to go
            await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel!")
        else:
            voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Could not download the song.")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added to the queue")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])
                print(self.music_queue)
                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)
                else:
                    print("normal")
```

This is my program, i am trying to create a discord music using discord.py and youtube_dl. this bot can handle individual songs pretty well, but if i want to queue the songs, it'll give me these errors:

```
[2023-08-22 12:08:14] [ERROR   ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command play
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python shits\discord bot\v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python shits\discord bot\v2\music_cog.py", line 70, in play
    await self.play_music(ctx)
  File "D:\python shits\discord bot\v2\music_cog.py", line 46, in play_music
    self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS),after=after_play)
  File "D:\python shits\discord bot\v2\venv\Lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 608, in play
    raise ClientException('Already playing audio.')
discord.errors.ClientException: Already playing audio.
```

i have no idea on why this happens.

I'm guessing it could be that my program was trying to play 2 songs at once, but I don't know how I can make them like wait till the other one complete.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set up your own variable to check whether the `VoiceClient` is playing or not. The library provides a method called `VoiceClient.is_playing()` which returns you a bool. 
Since you set your bool variable back and forth. It is common that `self.is_playing` becomes `False` when playing the queue, and you call `play` command at the same time to add a new track. Then, it will try to play a new piece of track while the old one is still playing, which will throw the error above.
It is suggestive to use the standard lib method to check the status of vc and always do `VoiceClient.pause()` before `.play()` to make sure the error will not be thrown.